# MediaStreamTrackGenerator available in Chrome DevTools but not in react app

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, mediastream, mediastreamtrack

I want to use the experimental [Insertable Stream for MediaStreamTrack API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Insertable_Streams_for_MediaStreamTrack_API) in my project, specifically, the [MediaStreamTrackGenerator](https://www.stackoverflow.com/).

The compatibility chart says it's supported from Chrome 94, and I'm using Chrome 109 (on Windows) so I figured it would be okay.

However, when ran `new MediaStreamTrackGenerator({kind: video})` in my local development version of my react app, I got the error:
`'MediaStreamTrackGenerator' is not defined  no-undef`.

First thought this is a problem with my chrome version so I ran the same line in my devtools console, and it worked there.

Then I thought this is because my node, npm, or react version not supporting this feature, so I updated them all to the latest version and it didn't help.**

A weird detail is that this error only appears after I make changes in my code (and it hot-reloads) or that I open devtools for my react app.

Answer (score 0):

Update: it seems like I just had to add `windows.` to it.